# How to deploy java application to EC2 like Heroku?

Tags: java, git, amazon-ec2

I really like Heroku style to commit the code and everything is deployed to the server. However, I'm building a java webservice which requires read/write file system. So, heroku is not the best option for me. So, I think my best option would be to host it on EC2. However,  I want to setup something like when I committed the code and push to Github it also pushes to EC2 server as well.

So, Github would be just a source control, but the server is on EC2. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Heroku allows local file system access for temporary files. Is that all you're looking for or are you persisting data via file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use AWS Elastic Beanstalk, which manages server/app container for you.

You can find more information here: http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/

Comment: But can I read/write filesystem on the beanstalk? Also, Is there a script to deploy that instead of uploading file manually?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. [Java on Play or Spring stack for example can run on Heroku.](http://blog.heroku.com/archives/2011/8/29/play/)

[Check this article to view all the stacks supported by Heroku.](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cedar)